# Trying to find polynomial-time algorithms for knapsack-like problems

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Consider two related problems:

1. You have $n$ cannisters that must go into $m$ trucks that can each carry $k$ cannisters. You require that no truck becomes overloaded, and for each cannister, there is a specified subset of trucks in which it may be safely carried. Is there a way to load all $n$ cannisters into the $m$ trucks such that no truck is overloaded, and each cannisters goes into a truck that is allowed to carry it?
2. Now, any cannisters can be placed in any truck, but there are certain pairs of cannisters that cannot be placed together in the same truck. Is there a way to load all $n$ cannisters into the $m$ trucks such that no truck is overloaded, and no two cannisters are placed in the same truck when they're not supposed to be?

The question I have is whether either of these has a polynomial-time algorithm to solve it. When I think in terms of greedy algorithms, I can't really come up with anything, so is there a clever trick (or algorithm paradigm) that can be used to solve these in polynomial time?

Answer (score 1):

For question (1), yes, there is, using maximum matching / flow. Consider the bipartite graph $(L, R)$ -- each of the nodes $l_i$ in $L$ correspond to a canister, and each of the nodes $r_i$ in $R$ correspond to a truck. For every pair of allowed canister $(l_i, r_i)$, such that it is allowed to put canister $l_i$ inside truck $r_i$, construct an edge with capacity $1$ between them. Now, add two additional nodes $v_t$ and $v_s$. Add an edge from $v_t$ to every canister $l_i$, each with capacity $1$. Add an edge from every truck $r_i$ to $v_s$ with capacity $k$. A maximum flow in this graph corresponds to an assignment of canisters to trucks.

Question (2) is NP-hard, because [Clique Cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover_problem) can be reduced to this problem by setting $k=n$ and considers the complement graph.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a clever trick for approximating solutions to the knapsack problem. Since the knapsack problem is pseudo polynomial, we can find a full approximation scheme for it such that out approximation can be made arbitrarily close. The details are here:

http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18434S06/knapsack-katherine.pdf

Basically, the trick is rounding your numbers.